# How to make a tabitem to be rendered only after the user clicks it - shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I´ve been looking for the solution to this but I do not find it

My issue is that I have a shiny dashboard that looks like this:

[image]

It is selecting all tabs even If I do not select them (like pre-rendered)

I tried making an observeEvent with a button but It do not know how to make the UI appear after they click it.

My code is

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


gamestop <- tags$img(src = "GSLL.png",
                     height = '30', width = '170')




ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "yellow",
                    
                    
                    
     dashboardHeader(title = gamestop,
                     dropdownMenu(type = "tasks",
                                  messageItem(
                                      from = "My contact",
                                      message = "x",
                                      icon = icon("glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"),
                                      href = "mailto:x"),
                                  messageItem(
                                      from = "Leads",
                                      message = "y",
                                      icon = icon("glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"),
                                      href = "mailto:y"),
                                  messageItem(
                                      from = "",
                                      message = "z",
                                      icon = icon("glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"),
                                      href = "mailto:z"),
                                      icon = icon("envelope")
                                  )
                     
                     ),
     
     
     
    dashboardSidebar( 
            sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Main menu", tabName = "main_menu", icon = icon("home")),
                        menuItem("Peripherals", tabName = "peripherals", icon = icon("hdd")),
                        menuItem("Database repair", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
                        menuItem("Polling", tabName = "polling", icon = icon("cloud")),
                        menuItem("more issues!!", tabName = "issues", icon = icon("ad"))
                        
                        )
                    ),
     
                    
    dashboardBody(tags$head(
                  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "Custom.css")),
                    
                        
                        
fluidPage(
                
                
                        tabItem(tabName = "peripherals",
                            h1("Peripherals",  
                                   style = "color:#15942B"),
                            
                            
                            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                        tabPanel("Printers",br(),
                                                 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                             tabPanel("M452DW",br(),
                                                                      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                                                  tabPanel("Not pinging"),
                                                                                  
                                                                                  
                                                                                  
                                                                                  tabPanel("Error messages")
                                                                                  )
                                                                      ),
                                                             tabPanel("M402DW",br(),
                                                                      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                                                  tabPanel("Not pinging")
                                                                                  
                                                                                  ),
                                                                      
                                                                      
                                                                                  
                                                                      )
                                                 )
                                                 ),
                                        
                                        
                                        tabPanel("Pinpad",br(),
                                                 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                             tabPanel("Offline / busy"),
                                                             
                                                             
                                                             tabPanel("Not turning on")
                                                             )
                                                 ),
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        tabPanel("Scanners",br(),
                                                 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                             tabPanel("GBT4400"),
                                                             
                                                             
                                                             
                                                             tabPanel("DS2278")
                                                             )
                                                 ),
                                        
                                        tabPanel("Receipt printer / cashdrawer",br(),
                                                 
                                                 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                             tabPanel("Receipt printer"),
                                                             
                                                             tabPanel("Cash drawer")
                                                             )
                                                 ),
                                        
                                        tabPanel("Label printer",br(),
                                                 tabsetPanel(type ="tabs",
                                                             tabPanel("ZD410"),
                                                             tabPanel("LP2824 & +")
                                                             ),
                                                 
                                                 )
                                        )
                            
                            
                                ),    #Final tab peripherals
                
                
                tabItem(tabName = "main_menu",
                        h1("Main menu",  
                           style = "color:#15942B"),
                        strong("Here we can add the news of the day or a welcome image"),br(),
                        br(),
                        br(),
                        strong("This is a work in progress, to be presented to our team leads so we can make
                                   it an aid page for all of us")
                       ),
                
                
                tabItem(tabName = "issues",
                        h1("More issue resolutions to come!!!!!",
                           style  = "color:#15942B" ),
                        strong("My plan is to add the hardest issue resolutions for our team, so they can access this web page and
                               with a glipse they can resolve the issue in hand")
                        ),
                
                tabItem(tabName = "polling",
                        )
                
                
                
                            ) 
                        )
                    )
)







server <- function(input, output) {
    
observeEvent(input$tabs, 
             if(input$sidebarmenu == "Printers"){
    
})
    
    
    
    
    
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to know how to render the tab when the user clicks on the tab itself and not before

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Maybe you find the answer here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinydashboard-render-only-the-clicked-tab/36493/4

Comment: I added to your code a second tabset panel and tabpanel, but the issue persists - when I click on the fist tab all tabs are getting rendered or "active"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the tab when the user clicks on the tab, you need to observe the tabsetpanel and check if the tab is clicked.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabItem(tabName = "peripherals",
          h1("Peripherals",  
             style = "color:#15942B"),
          
          
          tabsetPanel(id = "firsttabset",
                      type = "tabs",
                      tabPanel("Printers"),
                      tabPanel("Pinpad1", 
                               h1("Dies ist tab \"Pinpad1\""),
                               textOutput("text")),
                      tabPanel("Scanners"),
                      tabPanel("Receipt printer / cashdrawer"),
                      tabPanel("Label printer")
                      
          )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$firsttabset, {
               
               if(input$firsttabset == "Pinpad1") {
                 cat("tab \"Pinpad1\" is now being rendered \n")
                 output$text <- renderText({"tadaa"})
               } 
              
             
    })
  
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT: If you want to apply this to nested tabsetpanels, I found a way by observing both `tabsetpanel1` and `tabsetpanel2` and checking in the conditions which tabs are selected. I suppose the first tab of `tabsetpanel2`, that is `Scanners2` in this example, has to be rendered if you want to render the tab `Pinpad1`.

Check it out if it works for you. This logic can be extended to further nesting of tabsetpanels, but it will get complicated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabItem(tabName = "peripherals",
          h1("Peripherals",  
             style = "color:#15942B"),
          
          
          tabsetPanel(id = "firsttabset",
                      type = "tabs",
                      tabPanel("Printers"),
                      tabPanel("Pinpad1", 
                               tabsetPanel(id = "secondtabset",
                                           type = "tabs",
                                           tabPanel("Scanners2",
                                                    h1("Dies ist tab \"Scanners2\"")),
                                           tabPanel("Pinpad2",
                                                    h1("Dies ist tab \"Pinpad2\""),
                                                    textOutput("text2"))),
                               h1("Dies ist tab \"Pinpad1\""),
                               textOutput("text")),
                      tabPanel("Scanners"),
                      tabPanel("Receipt printer / cashdrawer"),
                      tabPanel("Label printer")
                      
          )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(c(input$firsttabset,
                 input$secondtabset), {
               
               if(input$firsttabset == "Pinpad1" & input$secondtabset == "Scanners2") {
                 cat("tab \"Pinpad1\" is now being rendered \n")
                 output$text <- renderText({"tadaa"})
               } 
              
              if (input$firsttabset == "Pinpad1" & input$secondtabset == "Pinpad2") {
                 cat("tab2 \"Pinpad2\" is now being rendered \n")
                 output$text2 <- renderText({"tadooo"})
                 
               }
    
    })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I added to your code a second tabset panel and tabpanel, but the issue persists - when I click on the fist tab all tabs are getting rendered or "active"